# How can I replace Polygon by Line in the output of ParametricPlot3D while preserving colours?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

```
{m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7} = {4, 3, 2, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4};
r = Sin[m0*phi]^m1 + Cos[m2*phi]^m3 + Sin[m4*theta]^m5 + Cos[m6*theta]^m7;
g = ParametricPlot3D[{r*Sin[phi]*Cos[theta], r*Cos[phi], 
    r*Sin[phi]*Sin[theta]}, {phi, 0, Pi}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue}, #] &), 
   Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> 0];
g /. Polygon -> Line
```

gives this:

[image]

The colour information is gone.

I want to get the output below:

[image]

How can I get it?

Comment: How did you get the second graphic?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I get the second graphics from python's lib enthought.mayavi. http://hyry.dip.jp:8000/pydoc/mlab_and_mayavi.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
Normal[g] /. Polygon -> Line
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Polygon colours are usually specified using the `VertexColors` option.  This works both in `Polygon` and in `Line`, so the colour should be preserved when you do a simple replace operation.  But `ParametricPlot3D` will produce a `GraphicsComplex` and will place the `VertexColor` option inside `GraphicsComplex` instead of `Polygon`.

`Normal` will simply get rid of the `GraphicsComplex`.